# Full height sidebar same like Wordpress with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sidebar

I'm working on a web app with a tools sidebar. Although the content is fluid, that sidebar must have a fixed width.

I try with flexbox, but the main box only take the height of the viewport, not the whole site content. Here what I did:

https://jsfiddle.net/junihh/eup7m608/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Holy Grail</title>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                vertical-align: baseline;
                -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                list-style: none;
                outline: 0;
            }

            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                font: normal 18px/120% Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            }

            article, aside {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
            }

            body {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
            }

            header, footer {
                height: 100px;
            }

            .main {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex: 1;
            }

            article {
                flex: 5;
                background-color: #EEE;
            }

            aside {
                background-color: #333;
                flex: 1;
                color: #CCC;
                width: 360px;
            }

            .margin {
                padding: 25px;
            }

            h1 {
                margin-bottom: 25px;
                font-size: 24px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            p {
                margin-bottom: 14px;
                line-height: 140%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="main">
            <aside>
                <div class="margin">
                    <h1>Aside</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                </div>
            </aside>
            <article>
                <div class="margin">
                    <h1>Article</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I even try with fix position of the sidebar but fail of what I need.

Any help of what to do? I need something like Wordpress sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your styles. Thing you misplaced was `display: flex` for `<body>`, which prevented it from growing with it's content.

#### Key part

Basically all I've done was removing these lines:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

#### Snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Holy Grail</title>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                border: 0;
                vertical-align: baseline;
                -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
                list-style: none;
                outline: 0;
            }

            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                font: normal 18px/120% Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
            }

            article, aside {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                border-radius: 0;
            }

            header, footer {
                height: 100px;
            }

            .main {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex: 1;
                align-self: stretch;
                min-height: 100%;
            }

            article {
                flex: 5;
                background-color: #EEE;
            }

            aside {
                background-color: #333;
                flex: 1;
                color: #CCC;
                width: 360px;
            }

            .margin {
                padding: 25px;
            }

            h1 {
                margin-bottom: 25px;
                font-size: 24px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            p {
                margin-bottom: 14px;
                line-height: 140%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="main">
            <aside>
                <div class="margin">
                    <h1>Aside</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                </div>
            </aside>
            <article>
                <div class="margin">
                    <h1>Article</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit vero consequuntur natus ullam 
                    minus ipsum reiciendis error voluptas deserunt hic quae amet, similique repudiandae rerum nesciunt a 
                    aperiam doloribus! Rem quae, fugit quibusdam saepe!</p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer @Andrzej. With many content that fix is great but with a less content I get a white space that I don't want. Because that I set that fix to the body. That is the reason why I published this question. Here what I get with that fix: https://jsfiddle.net/junihh/eup7m608/9/

Comment: [I updated your friddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq20yb7v/). I also edited snippet in my answer. I added `min-height: 100%` to `.main`. Is it OK for you now?

Comment: YES! Is right what I need! Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Nice to hear that! Don't hesitate to ask again and lastly I would to encourage you to [split CSS style sheets from your HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp). Thanks to it it's much easier to read code.